# How do I make WordPress send an email to the user when his account gets approved (manual by me)

Tags: email, user-registration

I was wondering if I could make it so that if I approve a user account via "Users" UI that an automatic email is sent to the user saying something like "Hey, your account on www.website.com has been approved, thanks for your patience!"

Is this possible in WordPress core, or is this something that has to be added manually?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: WordPress core doesn't even have a method for 'approving' users at all, so the answer would depend entirely on how you'd implemented that functionality. Are you using a plugin?

Comment: Hello there, I just found out that WP Forms (plugin) adds this functionality, so I'll probably have to contact them.

Comment: I found that WP Forms add a field `wpforms-pending` to the `wp_user_meta` table, so this is probably the field I'm looking for. This issue is not solved as it not a WordPress core issue.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do - approve a user in the admin and send an email - must be done using action and filter hooks, either by a plugin you're using or your own code in your child theme or a plugin.

To approve a user, take a look at the `user_register`, `edit_user_profile`, `edit_user_profile_update` and `load-user-edit.php` hooks to get started. In your own approval code, you would then structure your email and send it with the `wp_mail()` function.

Try searching the net for detailed solutions, you should be able to find blog posts with ready code.

Comment: I found out how it works, it's the plugin WPForms that stores a wpforms-peding status in the db. I'm checking if I can watch for changes to this value and trigger an email when it happens! Thank for you explanation!

Very helpful if I ever need to construct this myself from scratch!